# Creating a folder with the current git branch as the name

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs

I'm looking for a way to create a local test folder which represents the branch name which should be the current git branch that's checked out.

For instance if you're working on a stylesheet in the branch `feature/stable-test`, and you run a grunt task that compiles code than as a destination you would get `/stable-test/style.css`.

I've looked at [grunt-githash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-githash) and [grunt-gitinfo](https://github.com/damkraw/grunt-gitinfo) but they both return a empty object when I query `<%= gitinfo.local.branch %>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git branch | grep "\*" | cut -d " " -f2 | xargs mkdir
```

will create a folder named as the current branch.

As you tagged this question with `node.js`, I'd like to add:

You can use a node plugin like [simple-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git) get the current branch or use [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to call git directly.

```
# git branch
  autogenerated
* generated
  master
```

You'll get a list of branches, the current one is the one with the star. Select this line, cut the first two signes and use the name.